# Issue with building Elixir and beam on Alpine Linux

Tags: alpine-linux

I am running a build with Alpine linux 3.12 and build fails with the following output indicating an error building beam and ERTS with a C++ dependency.

```
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.3.2.1/bin/beam.smp: _ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.3.2.1/bin/beam.smp: pthread_getname_np: symbol not found
```

So far I have been looking at threads on these two specific errors with various threads as to the failure.

Is there some dependency that may need updating?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It may be caused by [an update](https://github.com/erlang/docker-erlang-otp/commit/3ea4c3b43616445d5b621664d184ced1cc0e9c8e) of the Elixir image in [elixir:1.12.3-alpine](https://hub.docker.com/layers/elixir/library/elixir/1.12.3-alpine/images/sha256-dfd56e6330a52e27a58ab90cbe64df68dfc3e874c071b32a014ca80163e5ade8?context=explore), which bumped the base image from `alpine:3.14` to `alpine:3.16`.

If you build the Elixir release from `elixir:1.12.3-alpine` and try to run the release on an older alpine, you will hit this error because of the runtime image has an older musl version.

To fix it, you can upgrade the runtime image to `alpine:3.16`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can find the digest for a working version of the `elixir:1.12.3-alpine`, and build your release from that: `FROM elixir:1.12.3-alpine@sha256:<DIGEST>`.

Comment: Awesome! The upgrade to alpine:3.16 resolved the issue. Thank you for the informed and detailed answer!

Comment: I also had `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 hexpm/elixir:1.13.4-erlang-25.0.2-alpine-3.16.0 AS build` and then later in that Dockerfile `FROM alpine:3.13.3 AS app`, which is exactly the issue you well described.

Comment: @shouya Thank you very much. out of curiosity: How am I able to find the digest sha of an older image? In docker hub, I can only find the digest of the current docker image that (unfortunately) breaks my project, see https://hub.docker.com/_/elixir/tags?page=1&name=1.11-alpine